# How do I sort a random list of 7 numbers out of 35?

Tags: c#, list, sorting, random

I want to create a lotto-game and randomly pick 7 different numbers out of 35 numbers in C#. That is what I do in the code but I do not understand how to sort the numbers in ascending order. What I do is to pick out 7 numbers from a list that has 35 numbers and now I am so confused so I need help that at least put me in another way of thinking.lf someone could hlep me with this I would be very glad. I realize that I have messed it up some with the naming. That is (for instance) I create a list (winningNumber) that contains all but the 7 random numbers I want to sort but right now I need help to sort my messy thoughts out.

Here is the code.

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace Random_Lotto_Number_2021_05_28_SMART
 {
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rndLottoNumber = new Random();
        List<int> winningNumber = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 35; i++)
            winningNumber.Add(i);

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            int drawnNumber = rndLottoNumber.Next(winningNumber.Count);
            //Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write(winningNumber[drawnNumber] + ",");
            winningNumber.RemoveAt(drawnNumber);
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"\nThe list contains {winningNumber.Count}");

        foreach(int num in winningNumber)
        {
            Console.Write(num + ",");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: Just put the numbers in a list and sort them. See duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add your "lucky" drawn numbers to a new list, and then sort that list, as shown below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
                
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Random rndLottoNumber = new Random();
        List<int> winningNumber = new List<int>();
        List<int> drawnNumberList = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 35; i++)
            winningNumber.Add(i);

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            int drawnNumber = rndLottoNumber.Next(winningNumber.Count);
            // Add numbers to list
            drawnNumberList.Add(winningNumber[drawnNumber]);
            //Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write(winningNumber[drawnNumber] + ",");
            winningNumber.RemoveAt(drawnNumber);
        }

        Console.Write("\nThe list contains ");
        Console.WriteLine(winningNumber.Count);
    
        foreach(int num in winningNumber)
        {
            Console.Write(num + ",");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        // Sort the list
        drawnNumberList.Sort();
        foreach(int num in drawnNumberList)
        {
            Console.Write(num + ",");
        }
    }
}
```

A way to assist with these problems is to write down what you are trying to do on a piece of old-fashioned paper writing either a flowchart or pseudo-code.  I have used this countless times when trying to order my thoughts around a programming problem.